# Tool for manipulating YAML files?

Tags: docker, software-rec, yaml, maven

We want to implement a workflow that includes having YAML configuration files where we wish to change some of the contents before actually using them, and we are looking for a good command line tool to do this.

This can be as simple as setting a target-specific value (like an URL) in an existing node, but preferably would be able to add or modify whole blocks of the YAML file.  In a perfect world, I would like something as powerful as the axis in XSLT.

We will use this with Maven in Docker files, where we prefer Debian-based images, but not a strict requirement.

Answer (score 10):

[Mike Farah’s `yq`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) is my go-to tool for YAML manipulation. For example, using a Kubernetes namespace definition file:

- extract the namespace name:

  ```
    yq read deploy/namespace.yaml metadata.name
  ```
- add a label:

  ```
    yq write deploy/namespace.yaml metadata.labels.name demo
  ```

  (this will replace an existing node, or add a new one if there isn’t one already)

The `-i` option can be used to update files in-place.

You won’t find everything that XSLT tools can typically do (or [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for JSON), for example you won’t find tests on sub-expressions so you can’t (AFAIK) write the equivalent of “update this sub-node on nodes which have this other sub-node with this value”.

Comment: Seems that the syntax of yq is different nowadays (version 4.35.2) , to write/modify a file in place you would `yq -i '.metadata.labels.name="demo"' deploy/namespace.yaml`

Answer (score 3):

[Andrey Kislyuk's `yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) (which is a different `yq` from the one [mentioned by Stephen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/550292/116858)) is a Python wrapper around the well known JSON processor `jq`.

As it's a wrapper around `jq`, it allows you to do any processing on YAML files that `jq` would normally do on JSON files. It also adds the ability to do in-place editing of files.

The `yq` utility can also output JSON, TOML, and XML. By installing `yq`, you get additional command line tools for working with these other types of structured document formats (`tomlq` and `xq` for TOML and XML, respectively).

The `yq` utility is available on OpenBSD, FreeBSD, and NetBSD as the `yq` package and on macOS as the Homebrew package `python-yq`. On GNU systems, you may install `yq` using `pip3` (`pip3 install yq`, or variations thereof).  See also Andrey's [installation instructions](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/#installation) for `yq`.