# How to remove a top-level entry and all of the nodes below it from a YAML file?

Tags: text-processing, yaml

My file contains the below entries:

```
cat /tmp/test.yaml
---
10.8.8.26:
  /tmp/win5835113081224811756.jar:
    hash: e6df90d38fa86f0e289f73d79cd2cfd2a29954eb

  /tmp/win03745991442278706.jar:
    hash: e6df90d38fa86f0e289f73d79cd2cfd2a29954eb

10.9.9.26:
  /tmp/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
    hash: 1746f03d57491b27158b0d3a48fca8b5fa85c0c2

  /tmp/conf/httpd.conf:
    hash: 1746f03d57491b27158b0d3a48fca8b5fa85c0c2
```

and so on...

I wish to delete a particular IP say 10.8.8.26 and it's file details from test.yaml

They below regex helps grab the details i wish to delete from the file and therefore i store it in a variable called check:

```
export check=`grep -Pzo '[^#](^10.8.8.26:)(.|\n)*^(?!( |\n))' /tmp/test.yaml`

echo $check
10.8.8.26: /tmp/win5835113081224811756.jar: hash: e6df90d38fa86f0e289f73d79cd2cfd2a29954eb /tmp/win03745991442278706.jar: hash: e6df90d38fa86f0e289f73d79cd2cfd2a29954eb
```

I then wanted to use the variable check to remove the grabbed entries from the file.

I tried the below commands but they do not help.

```
grep -v "$check" /tmp/test.yaml
```

And

```
sed "/${check}/d" /tmp/test.yaml sed: -e expression #1, char 1:
 unterminated address regex
```

Can you please suggest how can i fulfill my requirement?

Comment: You can't `grep` across multiple lines.

Comment: A more fundamental question is whether there are tools specifically for manipulating YAML files.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/550283/5132

Comment: Why not rephrase the title to "How to remove multiple lines after a match from a text file?"

Answer (score 0):

How far would

```
awk -v"DEL=10.8.8.26" '/^[0-9]/ {LP = 1} $0 ~ "^" DEL {LP = 0} LP' file
```

get you?

Try

```
awk -v"DEL=10.9.9.26" '/^[^ ]/ {LP = 1} $0 ~ "^" DEL {LP = 0} LP' file
```

"if the IP addresses are changed to hostnames." (from your comment). Would have helped to include that in the original question.

Comment: You'll avoid potential "trouble" from the Low-Quality-Review queue reviewers if you phrase your answers in the form of an Answer and not in the form of a Question :)

Comment: I guess the `awk` solution will fail if the IP addresses are changed to hostnames.

Comment: Guess the condition to remove text should be the line starting with the given IP upto the line that has white spaces in the start of the line.

Comment: Also be aware that the dots in an IP address have to be escaped when matching regular expressions.

Comment: @Rudic your solution works like a champ as i tried several permutations and combinations with both IP addresses and hostnames. I however, like a non-awk solution as awk errors when the input file has too lengthy content.